# Push notification toggle option not available in xcode 11 . Not even in the capability

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am working in ionic project and wants to add FCM Push notifications.
But I can't see toggle push notifications option in signing & Capabilities tab in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **signing and capabilities** tap `+ Capability` button and search push Notification according to official [**Apple docs**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding_capabilities_to_your_app)

[image]

Comment: I do not found 'Push notification' after search as well

Comment: do you have teamviewer ?

Comment: @Manpreet your apple account must be enrolled as a developer, pay 99 dollars to see that option :),
you can uncheck the automatic sign check box and then you can see it

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 11 there is little bit change everything so first open project editor and then click on **signing & capabilities** after you want click on + capability and you will see the push notification option where you can add this on your project.

and also remember another thing make sure you also add push notification on your certificate.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKb9U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this official [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding_capabilities_to_your_app) for the same.